# Opennms Availability by node

Tags: java, restful-authentication, opennms

I am working on OpenNMS. I want to get the report of "Availability by node" by Restful services. But I don't have any rest URL and API in XML/JSON form.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the REST endpoint "availability" to get access to service availability. Here is an example getting availability data from a specific node from the publicly available demo system.

- https://demo.opennms.org/opennms/rest/availability/nodes/49

It is also possible to get the availability data from categories or nodes within an availability category.

- https://demo.opennms.org/opennms/rest/availability/categories/Email+Servers
- https://demo.opennms.org/opennms/rest/availability/categories/Email+Servers/nodes/34

In hope this helps.

Comment: The data is generated from the Real Time Console (RTC) which is also the place for the documentation of this REST endpoint. See here:  http://docs.opennms.org/opennms/releases/21.0.5/guide-development/guide-development.html#_realtime_console_data